# Cancel alarm using a switch

Tags: android, sql, adapter, alarmmanager, alarm

Hello I'm attempting to disable and alarm using a switch and getting the specific alarm ID from an SQL database currently i'm receiving a null reference whenever I try to disable it. I'm still working on it now but if someone could also take a quick look that would be great.

Creating the alarm on a list view adapter

```
final int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), id, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

intentArrayList.add(pendingIntent);
```

My attempt in canceling the database from a BaseAdapter.

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

cursor.moveToPosition(position);

if (mySwitch.isChecked()){

Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), Integer.toString(position) + "ENABLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} else {

String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alarm_code"));

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(view.getContext(),   Integer.valueOf(id), receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "DISABLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Current error message.....

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(android.content.Context)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error it's hand if you don't forget to put these two lines in

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
receiver = new Intent(view.getContext(), Alarm_Reciever.class);
```